# How to get facebook users chat status?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I couldn't find the API to check whether a user is available for chat in the [graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api).

Anyone has any idea if its documented anywhere?

Comment: It is not available in the API

Comment: Yeah. After spending hours I conclude there's no such API. I think people got the online status from Chat API via XXMP instead.